# Why does Soluto fail to run?

Tags: windows-vista, soluto

I have a Toshiba laptop running Windows Vista. On that computer, due to recent performances degradation, I chose to install [Soluto](http://www.soluto.com/) to improve boot speed, and lighten my Firefox installation.

I run it from two accounts, mine and my wife's one, which are both administrator accounts.

- On my account Soluto starts flawlessly, displaying an icon in notification bar and allowing me fine-tuning of Windows start-up
- On my wife account, when I click the Soluto icon in the start menu, a security dialog popups requiring me to allow execution of `Soluto.exe /runservice` which I accept. The soluto icon then appears for a short time in notification bar before to disappear, without any additional information.

What can I do to have Soluto running on both accounts ?

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked in the [Event Viewer](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Open-Event-Viewer)?